# Doctrine: any way to create a Doctrine_Query object from a PDOstatement object?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Any way to create a Doctrine_Query object from a PDOstatement object?

I need the query to pass it to a DoctrinePager object.

```
   $pdo = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();

   $sql = 'select * from organo_gestor'; //this raw sql will have a union

   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Doctrine 1.2.4.